# What is causing my component to unmount?

Tags: reactjs, preact

I'm making an app where I have an Overlay component and a Map component rendering behind it just like this:

```
<div>
   {showOverlay && <Overlay />}
   <Map /> // this component should mount once
</div>
```

The overlay is shown to let the map load underneath but when I remove the Overlay (set showOverlay to false here) the `Map` component re-load.

At first I thought the `Map` component was just re-rendering, but after some digging I discovered that the component was actually re-mounting.

If I log in the `componentWillMount`, `componentWillUnmount` and `render` methods, the log appear in that order (which seems contradictory)

```
render
willUnmount
willMount
```

The parent does not re-mount, only the `Map` component do.

The Map component just render a div that reference a mapbox-gl-js map (like this https://gist.github.com/tristen/5c4b346ae38892f732504e6785d87057#file-map-js)

What can cause my component to re-mount itself like that ?

Thanks !

Comment: Map calls ReactDOM directly. Don't do that.

Comment: @lux This was just an example code, my map component doesn't call ReactDOM directly

Comment: The contents of your `<div>` is basically an array with one or two elements. The `<Map/>`'s position in the array depends on wether the `<Overlay/>` is shown or not. Since `<Map/>`'s position changes, React does not know it is the same component. Try adding a `key` attribute to your `<Map/>`, to give React a hint that it is the same component wether or not `<Overlay/>` is showing.